# Find out which button was clicked from the Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, onitemclicklistener, custom-lists

In my application T have custom ListView with 2 buttons.Now what I want is when user clicks on a particular button in the ListView an async task is called which sends the few parameters to the server.The parameters are comming from the ArrayList.Now how will I come to know which button was clicked from the ListView and also at that particular position the same data should be sent from the ArrayList.

CustomAdapter.Java

```
public class SearchJobsCustomList extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String> ();


    public SearchJobsCustomList(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        super ();
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size ();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from (c).inflate (R.layout.custom_search_jobs_lists, viewGroup, false);
            resultp = data.get (i);
            view.setTag (resultp);
            TextView JobCode = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_job_code);
            TextView Category = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_name);
            TextView ExpYrs = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_yrs);
            TextView ExpMnths = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_mnths);
            TextView Date = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_date);
            Button bestCandidate = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.bt_best_candidates);
            Button appliedJobs = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.bt_applied_jobs);
            bestCandidate.setOnClickListener (this);
            appliedJobs.setOnClickListener (this);

            if (resultp.get ("counts").equals (0)) {
                bestCandidate.setFocusable (false);
                bestCandidate.setText (0);

            } else {
                bestCandidate.setText (resultp.get ("counts"));
            }

            if (resultp.get ("applied").equals (0)) {
                appliedJobs.setFocusable (false);
                appliedJobs.setText (0);

            } else {
                appliedJobs.setText (resultp.get ("applied"));
            }


            JobCode.setText (resultp.get ("code"));
            Category.setText (resultp.get ("category"));
            ExpYrs.setText (resultp.get ("minExp"));
            ExpMnths.setText (resultp.get ("maxExp"));
            Date.setText (resultp.get ("postedOn"));


        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId ()){
            case R.id.bt_best_candidates:
                BestCandidateDisplay display=new BestCandidateDisplay ();
                display.execute ();

        }

    }


    public class BestCandidateDisplay extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String response= HttpRequest.post ("https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/WebService/HsJobService.asmx/GetBestCandidates").send ("Vendor_IEntity_Code=" + "&IJob_Req_ID=" + resultp.get ("reqId") + "&IJob_Requestor_ID=" + resultp.get ("iReqId") + "&Mode=" + "TTL").body ();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

List Image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

public class SearchJobsCustomList extends BaseAdapter{
        Context context;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

        public SearchJobsCustomList(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
            super ();
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size ();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_search_jobs_lists, null, false);
                holder.JobCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_job_code);
                holder.Category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                holder.ExpYrs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_exp_yrs);
                holder.ExpMnths = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_exp_mnths);
                holder.Date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
                holder.bestCandidate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_best_candidates);
                holder.appliedJobs = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_applied_jobs);
                view.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }


            if (data.get(i).get("counts").equals("0")) {
                holder.bestCandidate.setFocusable (false);
                holder.bestCandidate.setText (0);

            } else {
                holder.bestCandidate.setText (data.get(i).get("counts"));
            }

            if (data.get(i).get("applied").equals("0")) {
                holder.appliedJobs.setFocusable (false);
                holder.appliedJobs.setText (0);

            } else {
                holder.appliedJobs.setText (data.get(i).get ("applied"));
            }


            holder.JobCode.setText (data.get(i).get("code"));
            holder.Category.setText (data.get(i).get("category"));
            holder.ExpYrs.setText (data.get(i).get("minExp"));
            holder.ExpMnths.setText (data.get(i).get("maxExp"));
            holder.Date.setText (data.get(i).get("postedOn"));

            holder.appliedJobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    HashMap<String,String> row = data.get(i);
                    BestCandidateDisplay display=new BestCandidateDisplay ();
                    display.execute(row.get("reqId"), row.get("reqId"));
                }
            });

            holder.appliedJobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    HashMap<String,String> row = data.get(i);
                    BestCandidateDisplay display=new BestCandidateDisplay ();
                    display.execute(row.get("reqId"),row.get("reqId"));
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView Category;
            TextView ExpYrs;
            TextView ExpMnths;
            TextView Date;
            TextView JobCode;
            Button bestCandidate;
            Button appliedJobs;
        }
    }

    public class BestCandidateDisplay extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String response= HttpRequest.post("https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/WebService/HsJobService.asmx/GetBestCandidates").send ("Vendor_IEntity_Code=" + "&IJob_Req_ID=" +strings[0]+ "&IJob_Requestor_ID=" +strings[1]+ "&Mode=" + "TTL").body ();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like below,

-First set tags to your `Button` in `getView()` after `Button` initialization,

```
bestCandidate.setTag(i);
```

Then in the `onClick` method, you can do below to get the `Button` tag which is the list row position,

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId ()){
            case R.id.bt_best_candidates:

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), view.getTag()+" is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BestCandidateDisplay display=new BestCandidateDisplay ();
            display.execute ();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

in **getView** it self you can use **onclick**

after setting the text use like this

```
appliedJobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // your code here 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The view you get passed in on `onClick()` is the Button you are looking for.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // 1) Possibly check for instance of first 
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: which view?? i dint get you

Comment: at this line  `public void onClick(View view) {`

Comment: ok and how should i send the params cos i wil hav to find the position which the user selects and give that position to the arrayLIst

Answer (score 1):

just set the tag with the buttons like this.

```
bestCandidate.setTag(10*i+1);
appliedJobs.setTag(10*i+2);
```

and in onClick method the position of the item in list can be calculated by reverse process like this

```
int tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
int pos = (tag - 1)/10;
// or
int pos = (tag - 2)/10;
```

or try this

```
bestCandidate.setTag(10*i);
    appliedJobs.setTag(10*i);

bestCandidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag();

            }
        });
        appliedJobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag();


            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks bt sir plz can you explain me in more detail how this wil work??

Comment: see when you create a cell in a listView, you know the position of cell so you can set the tag of button with its position. see my edited anwser

Answer (score 0):

```
    onClick(View v){

       int id=v.getId();

       if(id==R.id.matching_jobs){
          ............write your code.........
       }
       else if(id== R.id.applied_jobs){
          ...............write your code..........
       }

    }
```

this may help you...

Comment: No, this won't work. Multiple buttons share same ID.

Comment: That's not good for readability. `if else if else if else...` for `int` is also not that good.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView()` method for Custom Adapter you can trigger `onClick` event for your both Buttons.

```
appliedJobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // your code here 
        }
    });

MatchingJobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // your code here 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding your custom adapter's `onClick` method and executing your `AsyncTask` from there, attach an OnClickListener while you define your Button within the `getView()` method. For example, while defining your `Buttons` within your `getView()` method:

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    if (view == null) 
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from (c).inflate (R.layout.custom_search_jobs_lists, viewGroup, false);
    }

    Button bestCandidate = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.bt_best_candidates);
    bestCandidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               // Start your AsyncTask here.

            }   
    }); 

    Button appliedJobs = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.bt_applied_jobs);
    appliedJobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               // Start your AsyncTask here.

            }   
    }); 

 ........
} // end of getView()
```

An advantage of this approach is that it ensures that you needn't worry about finding the positions of the list item elements that contain the buttons which were clicked during execution time as they are bound to the view (list item) that is inflated by your `LayoutInflater` in your `getView()` method. There is also a good chance that your list may expand beyond the size of the screen causing your `ListView` to recycle its elements, meaning that if for example you want to change the background-color of your list item on a Button click, you will experiece unexpected results. Implementing your `OnClickListeners` within the `getView()` method can also help you manage this situation by manipulating the positions of the list items within the `getView()` method itself as it is readily available as an argument of the method.